# How to update textarea and iron-autogrow-textarea text values in Polymer 1.0?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have setup two way binding with a normal `textarea` in Polymer using:

```
<textarea id="textbox" value="{{editText::input}}" autofocus></textarea>
```

I've also tried a two way binding `iron-autogrow-textarea` using the bindValue attribute:

```
<iron-autogrow-textarea bindValue="{{editText}}" class="fit" autofocus></iron-autogrow-textarea>
```

The property `editText` is assigned as follows:

```
Polymer({
  is: "page-editor",
  properties: {
    editText: {
      type: String,
      value: ""
    }
  },
```

But when change the `editText` in code below it won't update the respective textarea values...

```
this.editText = "new message";
```

Interestingly a console.log(this.editText) says its 'undefined'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct attribute to use is `bind-value="{{editText}}"`. CamelCase properties are translated to attributes with dashes ([source](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#property-name-mapping)).

Comment: I'm accepting this as the solution for 2-way binding with 'iron-autogrow-textarea'. The problem was fixed by using hyphenated attribute -  `<iron-autogrow-textarea bind-value="{{editText}}" class="fit">`

Answer (score 1):

I'm still ramping up on Polymer, but I think you need to set `notify` to `true`.

```
Polymer({
  is: "page-editor",
  properties: {
    editText: {
      type: String,
      value: "",
+     notify: true
    }
  },
...
```

If that doesn't work, post a full sample and I'll be happy to debug with you.

You can add an event listener with Polymer's `on-*` syntax, where `*` is the event to listen for.

```
<iron-autogrow-textarea bindValue="{{editText}}" 
                        class="fit" 
                        on-click="f' 
                        autofocus></iron-autogrow-textarea>
```

Define the event listener:

```
Polymer({
  is: "page-editor",
  properties: {
    editText: {
      type: String,
      value: "",
      notify: true
    }
  },
  /* the function signature below may be wrong...
   * don't know how many arguments it takes... */
  f: function(e, detail, sender) {
    this.editText = 'yay';
  }
...
```

Comment: Ah it's because the `this` comes from a button event so it's not getting the right reference to Polymer 'this' - is there a nice way to handle this? (pun not intended)

Comment: Ok, so I got `textarea` working by setting a var `self = this;` and using self.editText to change text... but  `iron-autogrow-textarea` doesn't work with the double bindings - am I missing something there?

Comment: See updated answer. Again, I'm new to this to, so take my help with a grain of salt. It would be much easier if you posted the full example, too.